# AWS IOT MQTT with Persistent Session- subscribe failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot

While experimenting with AWS IOT MQTT with Persistent Session I found that Broker returns 'session_present = True' in reply to connection request having 'clean_session = False'.
Which is expected as I reconnected within 60 mins as specified by AWS Documentation ( practically it was less than 5 mins )

I am using [aws-iot-device-sdk-python-v2](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-python-v2)

Issue :
      As per the theory , if 'session_present = True' then the broker stores ass previous session's info hence no need to subscribe to topics again.
But if I skip the step of subscribing to the topic then no messages received.
Is it the obvious behavior ? do I need to unsubscribe even though 'session_present = True' ?

Comment: Hello did you find anything regarding this ? As per the doc what you say is true "If sessionPresent is set to 1, a persistent session is present and stored messages are delivered to the client. This starts immediately after the device receives the CONNACK. There is no need to resubscribe. If sessionPresent is set to 0, no persistent session is present and the client must resubscribe to its topic filters."

Answer (score 0):

You need to update IoT policy to set PersistentConnect to work persistent session feature.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/connect-policy.html